# Unable to create cluster on Databricks Community Edition

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition

I have been using Databricks Community Edition for over 4 years and suddenly I'm unable to create a single node cluster as I have always been doing.

I keep on getting the message 'Only professional or enterprise tier customers can create autoscaling clusters' see image, but I don't see an option no not create an autoscaling cluster.

Have Databricks pulled the plug on Databricks Community Edition users? Or is there something that I'm doing wrong?

I just want to use the Community Edition in simple manner I have been using it for the past 4 years .. with a single node.

[image]

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, what makes you say that? I haven't seen any comments about it online

Comment: It has fine yesterday. Today I'm not able to create a cluster in the community edition. Are you also unable to create a cluster?

Comment: @AlexOtt, I just checked your profile, but what should I be looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232092/discussion-between-alex-ott-and-patterson).